# Setting Frame width and height

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

The code below is created using tkinter in Python. It renders a frame on which it provides link to next frame and on next frame it provides link to previous frame. I am not getting how to set width and height of the frame. Please help.

```
import tkinter as tk
LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)
class ImgComp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)        
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

def qf(param):
    print(param)

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 1",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button1.pack()

class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page One", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda:controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()   

app = ImgComp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: `Frame( width=..., height=...)`  but it will change size if elements inside are smaller or if element outside is bigger and you use `fill`, `resize` - [Stop a Tkinter frame from resizing according to widget sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684484/stop-a-tkinter-frame-from-resizing-according-to-widget-sizes)

Comment: I removed the properties fill, expand from the code. On which Line of my code should I write Frame(width = 500, height = 300)

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where you're trying to set the width and height. Do you want each frame to be a different size?

Comment: If possible guide me for both. To keep all frames of same size and frames of different size. Usually I use to set width and height while creating Frame object but in this code I am not getting where to initialize those properties

Comment: Are you certain that you want to resize frames and not the actual window?

Comment: Also providing [a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would drastically improve the chances of this question getting answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change size of `container` you cat set `width` and `height`
and you have to use `grid_propagate(False)` to keep it.

```
    container = tk.Frame(self, width=500, height=250)
    #container['width'] = 500
    #container['height'] = 250
    container.grid_propagate(False)
```

[image]

If you add bacground to all `Pages` then you will see they use full size

```
frame = F(container, self)
frame['bg'] = 'red'
```

[image]

And now you can organize elements inside to use all area.

For example you can put button on the bottom using `pack(side='bottom')`

```
   button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 1", ...)
    button1.pack(side='bottom')
```

[image]